# ARM/Raspberry Pi asm delay

Tags: assembly, arm, delay, raspberry-pi

I tried to implement a delay on a Raspberry Pi running in ASM. (Bare metal)

But with my code I only reach a Frequence of 13.6Mhz or 13.6 Million subs+bne per Second but why Is this the case, the arm core is set in the config.txt to 700Mhz.

```
  __asm__ volatile ( "1: subs %0, %0, #1 \n\t"
                  "bne 1b"
                  : : "r"(cycles));
```

I have tested it by toogle an Output GPIO with nearly 100ms and divided afterwards.

Comment: I mean this means subs+bne needs 50 nop cycles before next subs+bne, this seems to be way too much?

Comment: Do you have the cache enabled?  Instructions can take more than one cycle, especially if they are branches.  Also, you may have to setup the system clock to run at 700MHz; it just means it is capable of running that fast.   It might not boot at that speed.

Comment: what was the value you started with, basically how many times through this loop are you expecting.  this is a tight loop you are trashing the pipe, it is going to be not even remotely close to 700Mhz even with really fast memory or l1 cache.  and it will just get slower from there.   This is a very bad way to do a delay, works great on some/older microcontrollers where the execution time is a bit more deterministic, but it wont work that way here.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about this, maybe i should make multiple "nops" (like 700 for 1us) but I didn't found a smart way to do this.

Comment: You mentioned you're running on bare metal, but you've said nothing about how you've set up the processor.  In my experience with ARMv7 based devices (the Raspberry Pi is an ARMv6 based device), you need to enable the MMU before the caches can cache properly.  Have you enabled the MMU (with an appropriate page table) along with the cache?  If not, then 50 cycles/iteration is not unexpected...

Comment: nope I'm not using the MMU, but there are other strange things too, the arm timer runs with 250Mhz like the gpu core instead of the 700Mhz of the "config.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be not the best way of implementing a delay, as you rely completely on the knowledge of the time it takes to execute the pair of instructions (sub, b), and this can change in different modes of operation, etc. etc.

I think you can try two different options, that will be valid for any operating condition, and I think, the are more reliable than your approach:

1. A busy wait: Get the value of the current system timer on entrance (t0). Loop. On each iteration, compare the count, and if it is a greater than your expected system timer value (t0+time_you_want_to_wait_in_secs·ticks/sec), then return.
2. An interrupt routine: Set a timer interrupt so you can do other things while waiting to your correct time.

You have all the information regarding the memory directions in which to get the system timer values in the [BCM2835 datasheet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).

Anyway, my intention is just to try and point out another set of solutions, so you can explore them if you want. The above answers are good ones for your specific code, I think ^^.

Comment: One critique to the busy-wait approach is that (from what I can find), the Raspberry Pi's user-readable clock runs at 1 MHz, which is 700 instruction cycles per tick - might not be good enough resolution for everyone.